# Admin Panel Redirecting to root

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, admin

When I moved from localhost to live, I did a find and replace on my database for anything with http://localhost and switched it out with my new url.
Now I've got a problem of my admin panel redirecting to the site root.

I noticed my url for admin is getting re-written and re-directed before logging in.

Say i went to http://www.mysites.com/wp-admin/

```
The url changes to http://www.mysites.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysites.com&reauth=1
```

What has messed up in my database? :(

Comment: You need to be logged in to see your admin panel.

Comment: Yes I realise this, but I'm unable to login in cause it keeps redirecting me to root. Then every time I try visit the admin panel again I have to repeat the process.

Comment: Fancy adding both the site root URL and your WP root URL?

Comment: Okay. This sounds like a cookie issue. Check inside your wp-config file, that you've set the new domain as well: `define('RELOCATE',true);`. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: http://staging.hemisphereinteractive.com/croxley/wp-admin

Comment: hakre: I've tried your approach but still hitting the same problem
The url i posted above redirects it back to staging.hemisphereinteractive.com when I login, when i re-vist wp-admin it's logged me in. But how come it's redirecting to root

Comment: Because you have borked some URL setting. Check the configuration within the admin. Moving an existing wp install across domains looks like a scenario that is not much thought of with wordpress, it's a hurdle since ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went wrong somewhere, did a clean install of wordpress and all was fixed again.